# chrome extension with service worker receiving push notifications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've successfully built a service worker that receives push notifications following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications).

And I was trying to build a chrome extension that would allow me to subcripe to the push notifications. But it seems that when the extension runs the service worker is not supported.

```
Service Worker Error :^( DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the current origin ('chrome-extension://dghajjpcbhcpnnkkgehjhhceemhcacoc') is not supported.
```

Am I missing some permissions on the manifest.js?

I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) for the Chrome extension.

Comment: using this for ref:
https://github.com/googlesamples/gcm-playground/tree/master/chrome

Comment: Have you found a solution or tutorial to this (with the service worker)? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: See newer post here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41350291/632951

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enabling Service Workers for Chrome extensions is still a work in progress. You can track it [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=545535). It seems that it is already available in the Canary and Dev channels.

You don't need a Service Worker to be able to receive push notifications in a Chrome extension. You can use the [`chrome.gcm` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/gcm).

Comment: Thanks for that. In that case...is it possible for me not to use a service worker to receive push notifications?
or is that my only option.

Comment: @rsanchez I'm also working on chrome extension and trying to use gcm for push notification. but problem is that gcm om.message event on runs when I click on extension, i.e, I don't think it's running in background. Can you help me out here?

Comment: @rsanchez, Using `gcm` is a bad idea as it ties you to Google: Google ain't Chromium.

Comment: I know you can use chrome.gcm to interact with cloud messaging. But does anyone know if this API is still valid for working with Firebase Cloud Messaging? I didn't see anything specific to FCM in the Chrome Extension APIs.

Comment: @RobReagan I'm looking for the same information about FCM, do you know if this API is still valid to work with FCM?

Comment: @KennyAlvizuris, I have built an extension that uses FCM and makes use of the chrome.gcm api in order to do so. So I can vouch that it works. As for how future-proof it is, as of two months ago I was unable to determine the answer.

Comment: @RobReagan did you see the api is deprecated since April 2018? https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client would that mean the chrome API would stop working too?

Comment: @KennyAlvizuris looks like we have until April 2019 to find a new way to do this. I don't have a solid answer at the moment. If you find something, please tag me here and let me know. This will get a LOT more of my attention around January 2019 if it's not resolved by then. :-)

Comment: Has anyone found a FCM alternative to chrome.gcm.onMessage in Chrome extensions?

Comment: @RobReagan Have you figured out a solution to the GCM-to-FCM Chrome extension port yet?  I can't find _anything_ in Google/Firebase docs.  You claimed it would get more of your attention by January 2019 so you've set my hopes very high! ;)