# Chrome extension: Serviceworker cross origin failing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker

[Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) claim that:

> By adding hosts or host match patterns (or both) to the permissions section of the manifest file, the extension can request access to remote servers outside of its origin

My ≪manifest.json≫:

```
{"manifest_version":2,"name":"","version":"0","permissions":["http://example.org/"],"background":{"scripts":["asd"]}}
```

≪asd≫:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sdf.js',{scope:'http://example.org/'}).then(x=>console.log('done', x))
```

≪sdf.js≫:

```
addEventListener('fetch', e=> e.respondWith(new Response('url: '+e.request.url,{headers:{'content-type':'text/html'/*, etc*/}})))
```

I loaded the code using ≪Load unpacked extension≫; It crashed without any error message:

[image]

Apparently the code `"permissions":["http://example.org/"]` crashed the extension.

How to set permissions for Chrome Extension cross-origin serviceworker? Is there a required Chrome flag?

Comment: Simply not implemented, I guess. Try to do it in a content script of a tab/iframe that runs the site URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Tried with [code here](https://jsfiddle.net/jd2qvtgp/), but `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The origin of the provided scriptURL ('chrome-extension://pgmcjkmokcicmebpjlmblnhfnfgooghm') does not match the current origin ('https://example.org')`. Any other strategy?

Comment: If you're facing explicit crashes, [take a look at logs](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging).

Comment: As per spec `A service worker executes in the registering service worker client's origin` so you can't do cross-origin registrations.

Answer (score 1):

As various folks have pointed out in the comments, it's not possible for a service worker to control a Chrome Extension, and it's not possible to register a service worker scoped to an `https:` origin within the context of a Chrome Extension.

Comment: Does it still hold true?