# (How) Can a Chrome Extension listen for messages from my server?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, push-notification, messaging, service-worker

My Chrome Extension's background page is set up as an event page, i.e., most of the time it is asleep unless some registered event listener wakes it up.

I'd like to be able to occasionally send messages from my server to the event page of an individual user of my extension. They should not necessarily show up as a desktop notification, it would rather be up to the background script to decide what to do with any incoming message. It might very well store some information in localstorage for example. If the user client was offline at the moment the message is being sent, it would ideally be delivered once it comes back online.

I'd like to avoid polling my server at regular intervals every time the background script is awake, though that would be an obvious solution.

My question is therefore if it is possible to register a special kind of event in my event page so that it wakes up and triggers some functionality once there's an incoming message from my server. Ideally, the server message would not be a general broadcast to all my users, but rather a targeted message to a specific user.

What options do I have?

I read about service workers and their Push API but it seems they are only slowly being rolled out to Chrome Extensions. I am not sure if they are ready for the browser's stable release yet and didn't find any documentation on how they work with extensions. 
I also read a bit about Google Cloud Messaging but it is deprecated in favor of a new costly Firebase solution.

Comment: FWIW, a service worker can be registered in a chrome extension, not sure if it'll handle Push API, though.

Comment: @wOxxOm Not sure either about Push API, but the annoyance with it is that it relies on the user's full cooperation (i.e. notifications approval). Push is great as a "marketing tool" to make your customers use your app more, if they are open to it, but not as a remote control for your app from afar.

Answer (score 0):

**Service worker** functions like a proxy server, allowing you to modify requests and responses, replace them with items from its own cache, and more. While **Chrome** has its ***own approach*** to caching/installing the resources need to display a Chrome Extension. Therefore, there will be an error when you will attempt to intercept the registration of a service worker to a Chrome Extension.

See for more information:

- [Introduction to service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker)
- [Service Worker script errors if run in chrome extension](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3144)

See related SO post:

- [Chrome Extensions with service worker receiving push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699566/chrome-extension-with-service-worker-receiving-push-notifications)

Comment: It seems service worker functionality is still a work in progress with respect to Chrome Extensions - but even if they worked together, can they be triggered to do something from afar, i.e., receive and process a message received from a remote server? Or can they at least poll such a server at regular intervals to check if there are new messages?